# l want to add dynamic textbox

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, code-first

I have a problem with my program. I have three DB models, hotelcategory, hotelroom type and price. in some categories there are two but in some other there are three categories. we need to make textbox for every room in every category. after that I must post it like this: categoryID, roomİD,price. with for loop l didnt get it. how can l relate these categories to eaach other in arrayList.

```
  public class PrPrice
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int[] ProgramID { get; set; }
            public List<HotelRoomProgram> hotelRoomProgram { get; set; }
            public int[] hotelRoomProgramID { get; set; }
            public List<HotelCategoryProgram> hotelCategoryPrograms { get; set; }
            public int[] hotelCategoryProgramsID { get; set; }
            public decimal[] Price { get; set; }



        }
```

---

```
  for (int i = 0; i < Model.hotelCategoryPrograms.Count(); i++)
                                        {
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.hotelCategoryPrograms[i].HotelCategories.ID)
                                            <label>@Model.hotelCategoryPrograms[i].HotelCategories.Name</label>
                                            for (int a =0; a < Model.hotelRoomProgram.Count(); a++)
                                            {
                                               @Html.HiddenFor(x=> x.hotelRoomProgram[a].HotelRoomType.ID)
                                                <label>@Model.hotelRoomProgram[a].HotelRoomType.Name</label>
                                                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Price[a], new {id =a })
                                            }
```